# Does Autonomous Database offer same NLS support as on-premises database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Most of our databases are using French character set, date, currency, sort, etc. Some databases can also do OS calls and the OS can be in French as well. Can we state that all NLS Support features will behave the same in Autonomous DB as on-premises DB?

Answer (score 1):

The NLS params they can change in ADB-S are documented here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-restrictions-database-initialization-parameters.html#GUID-7CF648C1-0822-4602-8ED1-6F5719D6779E.

They cannot change the change the character set in ADB-S as of today, it uses UTF8. That's the unicode characterset that "catches it all" and can be used for your French databases are covered.

They cannot change the OS language, ADB-S is a managed service and will never allow OS changes.